# How to get keys of $data.Entity?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jaydata

I wanted to get the keys of an $data.Entity but I haven't found the solution on how to do it. I am not referring to the JSON keys but the Entity primary keys.

```
$data.Entity.extend("Kissa", {
      name: { type: 'int', key: true }
      , address : { type: 'int', key: true }
      , age : { type: 'int' }
});

$data.EntityContext.extend("KISSA_DB", {
                kissa: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: Kissa }
            });
```

Now, I have an object like this and I wanted to get the keys which are "name" and "address".

```
var temp = new Kissa({name: "Kim", address: "Mars", age: 20});
```

Is there an available API like :

```
temp.getType().getKeys()
```

Answer (score 1):

If `temp` is just a plain Object, then you can just use `Object.keys` and pass `temp` to it.

```
console.log(Object.keys(temp));
```

Comment: Nope. That's not what I meant, please check the fields with "key" set to true. I only need those.